# Creating a horizontal nav bar easily in a header

Tags: html, css, web

I have a certain Header with my Logo and title. Just to the right of the Title Mobility group I want to create a nav bar that touches the bottom of the header with different tabs all the way to the right of the header. Messing around I was able to create something, but I can't seem to position it correctly.

- http://jsfiddle.net/jHJK2/
- http://jsfiddle.net/jHJK2/embedded/result/

I just can't figure out how to add this navigation bar to my header div.

**HTML code**:

```
<div id="page">
    <div id="header">
        <a href="http://wireless.fm.intel.com/test/index.php">
            <img src="http://wireless.fm.intel.com/test/logo2.png" border=0 >
        </a>

         <h2><a href="http://moss.ger.ith.intel.com/sites/MWG-IS/Pages/Default.aspx" border=0>Mobility Group</a></h2>

        <div id="navigation"> 
            <a href="#">About</a>
            <a href="#">Reports</a>
            <a href="#">Documents</a>
            <a href="#">Checklists</a>
            <a href="#">License Tools</a>
            <a href="#">Presentations</a>
            <a href="#">Software Releases</a>
        </div>
    </div>
        
    <div id="main"></div>
    <div id="footer"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS Code**:

```css
html, body {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    height:100%;
}
#page {
    min-height:100%;
    position:relative;
    height:100%;
}
#header {
    background-color:#115EA2;
    height:100px;
    width:97.5;
}
#main {
    width:1300px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    background-color:#F1F2F3;
    min-height:90%;
    height:auto;
    height:89%;
    margin:0 auto -50px;
    vertical-align:bottom;
}
#footer {
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
    bottom:0;
    height:35px;
    background-color: #115EA2;
}
#header img {
    float:left;
    display:inline;
}
#header h2 {
    text-align:center;
    font-size:44px;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    left:0px;
    top:20px;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-family: Sans-serif;
    float:left;
    margin-top:20px;
    margin-left:20px;
    text-decoration:none;
}
#header h2, a, a:visited, a:hover, a:active {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

**Navigation Bar Code:**

```css
#navigation {
    position:relative;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    width:70%;
    background-color:gray;
    color:green;
    height:35px;
    text-align:center;
    padding-top:15px;
}
#navigation a {
    font-size:14px;
    padding-left:15px;
    padding-right:15px;
    color:black;
    text-decoration:none;
}
#navigation a:hover {
    color:blue;
}
```

#### Update

Just wanted to say Thank you all for your help.

Comment: Use a list! It'll make it much, much easier

Comment: [This tutorial](http://www.cssnewbie.com/super-simple-horizontal-navigation-bar/#.Ud9Te_mfj6k) would help you a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adapting your current method to a more html5 approach, you can use `header` and `nav` tags do better markup your document. Absolute positioning also gives you better control over your elements. You would set the header to a relative position, and the nav to absolute, and offset it by the height of your header.

```css
nav {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    min-width: 800px;
    text-align: left;
    height: 20px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
}
```

Here is your [**updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/jHJK2/4/)

And here is an update with the nav to the right, a bit messy though:
http://jsfiddle.net/jHJK2/5/

Comment: Thank you so much the first one looks really nice! The second one is the one I like the most except I dont't want it to fill the whole header. The position from left to right is perfect it ust needs to be moved down and have a small height and fit right in the header. If you get what I mean. Thanks though I will try to mess around with it a little bit!!!! @lukeocom

Comment: just change the top value to adjust the height. or remove the top value and it will use the current height value which is being ignored ;)

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure if this is how you want it since your request wasn't very clear, but here's what I made. 
http://jsfiddle.net/jHJK2/2/

Changes:

HTML:

```
<div id="header">
<div id="navigation"> //moved this before the other elements
        <a href="#">About</a>
        <a href="#">Reports</a>
        <a href="#">Documents</a>
        <a href="#">Checklists</a>
        <a href="#">License Tools</a>
        <a href="#">Presentations</a>
        <a href="#">Software Releases</a>
</div>
<a href="http://wireless.fm.intel.com/test/index.php">
    <img src="http://wireless.fm.intel.com/test/logo2.png" border=0>
</a>
<h2><a href="http://moss.ger.ith.intel.com/sites/MWG-IS/Pages/Default.aspx" border=0>Mobility Group</a></h2>

</div>
```

CSS:

```css
#navigation {
    width:100%;
    background-color:gray;
    color:green;
    height:35px;
    text-align:center;
    padding-top:15px;
}
#navigation a {
    font-size:14px;
    padding-left:15px;
    padding-right:15px;
    color:black;
    text-decoration:none;
}
#navigation a:hover {
    color:blue;
}
```

Comment: Hey @taylorc93 Thank you for your help! It looks good, but that is not what I was looking for. I was looking for more that the actually nav bar be in the header. Where you see the p in Mobility Group I want it to start there and end at the end of the header and fit all the tabs between that space. The height of the nav bar should be a little thing once we place it there. Maybe I can try and mess with the code a little bit and see if I can work soemthing out! Thank you for the help though!

Answer (score 0):

Make the following CSS changes:

[**Demo in jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/jHJK2/6/)

```css
#header {
    background-color:#115EA2;
    height:100px;
    width:97.5;
    position: relative;
}
#navigation {
    position:absolute;
    /* top:0;
       left:0;*/
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    width:70%;
    background-color:gray;
    color:green;
    height:35px;
    text-align:center;
    padding-top:15px;
}
```

Comment: Hello this looks really good to! I will try to mess around with it and see if I can get the desired result I want! Thank you!